# Unnumbered section titles have a strange behaviour

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using Rmarkdown and Knitr to write my Master degree memoir with a custom LaTeX template. Almost everything is ok but there is something bugging me.

The unnumbered section title doesn't work as expected.

I use the `{ - }` symbol at the end of the section title like it is said in the documentation.

The section is not numbered in the TOC but the actual section title is numbered with an asterisc and the title name is on line after (see pic from the abstract)

[image: Abstract bad section title]

You can see the result in the [pdf page 4](https://framagit.org/Roelandtn/reprex_bug_headers/blob/master/reprex_bug_headers.pdf).

You can clone a repoductible Rproject with:

```
git clone https://framagit.org/Roelandtn/reprex_bug_headers.git
```

I think the issue come from the custom template I use but I don't see why or how to correct this. Can someone look at it ?

How to reproduce:

- Clone the repo
- Open the Rproject with Rstudio
- Open the reprex_bug_headers.Rmd file
- Knit the pdf document

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Additionnal informations:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.4     yaml_2.1.18     Rcpp_0.12.16    stringi_1.1.7  
[10] rmarkdown_1.9   knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.0   digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: Open `etude.cls` and find the areas where `\section`, `\subsection`, ... are redefined. Then add a comment character `%` at the end of the definition (like in [this paste](https://pastebin.com/WP42Fw4H)). See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @Werner, actually it does ! Thanks a lot  ! I didn't understand why but it does.

Comment: I was proposing a bypass with a custom section title adapted from *mySection* macro in `etude.cls` but @werner's soltion is a real fix and far more elegant, so... How can I close this question (SO newbie) ?

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. You can vote on it and accept is as the correct answer by clicking the check mark underneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `etude.cls` template has a number of (unwanted) spurious spaces in the command definitions associated with sectional units. Specifically, you'll have to add line-ending comment characters `%` to avoid LaTeX missing the `*` when you want an unnumbered section. Here's what you need to update:

```
\renewcommand{\section}{
    \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}
    {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}
    {2.3ex plus.2ex}
    {\color{\SectionTitleColor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <---- comment character added
  %{\color{TextColor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
}
\renewcommand\subsection{
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
    {\color{\SectionTitleColor}\normalfont\large\bfseries}% <---- comment character added
  %{\color{TextColor}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{
      \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
      {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
      {\color{\SectionTitleColor}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% <---- comment character added
    %{\color{TextColor}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
}
\renewcommand\paragraph{
      \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
      {-1em}
      {\color{\SectionTitleColor}\normalfont\normalsize}% <---- comment character added
    %{\color{TextColor}\normalfont\normalsize}
}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{
      \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}
      {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
      {-1em}
      {\color{\SectionTitleColor}\normalfont\normalsize}% <---- comment character added
    %{\color{TextColor}\normalfont\normalsize}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, would not have find it by myself. It is a template I borrowed from another university, and I made it some Frankenstein monster. I can't vote (not enough rep points) but it is the right answer. :)